# Is there good library to do NMF fast?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, matrix, dimensionality-reduction

I have a sparse matrix whose shape is **570000*3000**.  I tried [nima](http://nimfa.biolab.si/) to do NMF (using the default nmf method, and set `max_iter` to 65). However, I found nimfa very slow. Have anyone used a faster library(can be used by Python/R) or software to do NMF?

Answer (score 0):

This question ([Sparse matrix factorization with Nimfa is very slow with implicit zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749356/sparse-matrix-factorization-with-nimfa-is-very-slow-with-implicit-zeros)) shows that you might want to try the .todense() version of the code perhaps?